# Yii2 Authentication fails

Tags: php, security, authentication, yii2

Today i came across with a probleme in Yii2 Authentication. I implemented succesfully but when i try to log in every time it shows me the following error:

[image]

After i refresh the page 1 or 2 times the error goes off and everything works properly. My first tought was to add the database field auth_key (32) varchar but it didn't solved the issue.

Here is my User.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Security;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;


class User extends ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'felhasznalo';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByFelhasznalonev($felhasznalonev)
    {
        return static::findOne(['felhasznalonev' => $felhasznalonev]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_Key;
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->auth_Key === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->jelszo === sha1($password);
    }
}
```

The login action:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {

        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            if (empty($_SESSION['ablak_id'])) {
                $_SESSION['ablak_id'] = Yii::$app->request->post('a_id');
            }
            else {
                return $this->redirect(Url::to(['ugyfelhivo/muszerfal/' . $_SESSION['ablak_id']]));
            }
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            $session = Yii::$app->session;
            $session->set('ablak_id', Yii::$app->request->post('ablak_id'));
            return $this->redirect(Url::to(['ugyfelhivo/muszerfal/' . $_SESSION['ablak_id']]));
        }

        //Lekérdezzük az elérhető rendelők nevét majde elküldjük kimenetre
        $ablakok = Ablak::find()->all();

        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
            'ablakok' => $ablakok,
        ]);
    }
```

And the LoginForm.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByFelhasznalonev($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

This is the table structure for the users table(felhasznalok == users in hungary)

[image]

Any ideas for the problem?

Thank your for Your answers!

Gábor

Comment: In User model you use `$this->auth_key` and `$this->auth_Key` (uppercase K). Is it the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply a typo, you should use `auth_key` instead of `auth_Key` :

```
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->auth_key === $authKey;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution! I was looking for that uppcercase K for 2 days now.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the *getUser* function in your *LoginForm* into:

```
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::findByFelhasznalonev($this->username);

        //generate auth_key for a new created User
        $this->_user->generateAuthKey();
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

Comment: Okay, i made the changes but now Yii throws **Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script** error in **LoginForm.php**

The declaration is right after the <?php tag.

Comment: Okay, it was my fault... I had some whitespace before the opening tag. Sorry for the silly question!

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same error: Getting unknown property: app\models\User::auth_Key